# Advantages of using MutableLiveData<String> over String?

Tags: android, kotlin

Here is my global object:

```
object FcmData {
    val type: String by lazy {
        String()
    }
    val type2: MutableLiveData<String> by lazy {
        MutableLiveData<String>()
    }
}
```

I'm using the `type` value to persist a value that can be updated and accessed by my service and fragment.

What is the difference, if any, when applying the two types in my use-case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LiveData` is an observable data holder class. So you should be using this when you need to track the value and run any actions according to its changes (ex: Databinding).

So if you are just reading/writing the value without observing - you should not be using LiveData

More about [livedata](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata)

Answer (score 1):

Those types are totally different and it's hard to find (dis)advantages between those two.

`String` is just an object. Actually, you use `delegate`, so access to that object is via `Lazy` delegate (value is initialized when it's used).

In the second case you use `MutableLiveData` which is wrapping the `String` into the object (and `MutableLiveData` is also wrapped in `Lazy` delegate). Whenever you update that data all observers will be notified. What is important that type comes from android library and it's available in `android-arch` library.

So, what's the difference between those two?

Both values are immutable. I mean there is no setter for those fields. But, you can change internal value of `type2`, because `MutableLiveData` has methods like `updateValue` and `postValue`, so it's immutable wrapper over mutable value.

In `type` you just initialize value lazily and you cannot change it.

If you look for some other possibilities than `MutableLiveData` you can look into `Observable` delegate that is available in `kotlin std lib`. That delegate can be compared to `MutableLiveData` (as does basically the same). The docs can be found here: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.properties/-delegates/observable.html